# How can I read a webpage in R and made a data table out of it

Tags: python, r

Here is the website and there are 5 properties

http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/SheriffSearch/results.aspx?q=searchType%3dZipCode%26searchString%3d44106%26foreclosureType%3d%26dateFrom%3d10%2f6%2f2016+12%3a00%3a00+AM%26dateTo%3d4%2f6%2f2017+11%3a59%3a59+PM

How I can read this website into R and make a table like this out of it

```
Address                         Prorated_Tax
1462 EAST 115TH STREET          $0.00
10531 37 LEE AVE                $0.00
10526 ORVILLE AVENUE            $0.00
1116 ASHBURY AVENUE             $0.00
2780 EAST OVERLOOK              $0.00
```

or Can I do it in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is rather broad, but i can give some suggestions.

What you're trying to do here is called scraping. There is an article on how to do it in python here:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/
the basic idea is to fetch the webpage using the `requests` module, and then you parse it into an XML tree using `lxml` and get your values from that tree.

Of course, it would be better if you had a more direct access to these data, like from a rest api or a database. Scraping is vulnerable, because when the design and structure of the webpage changes, the scraping code stops working until you've adjusted it accordingly.

If this is a script that you only run once, or over a limited time period, and if the amount of data is not too big, this method is perfectly fine.

There are also probably equivalent libraries for R if you search for it.

Comment: Thanks Mailard, That's a good start for me to learn

Answer (score 2):

Using bash you may use the curl command

```
website = "www.interestingsite.com"
cmd = paste( "curl", website, "> temp" )
system( cmd )
```

the html content of the website will then be stored in this temp file, by going through you can extract its content.

Comment: Thanks !! I will look this up